# How to make a discord bot reply to a new message after the first one is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a math minigame command of some sorts and I'm trying to make my bot check the newest message sent for the answer of the math problem instead of the message that started the command

I tried using this but it wont check the newest sent message, rather it checks the first message with "s!mathMinigame" instead

```
if(message.content === "s!mathMinigame"){
      var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      message.reply(`${number1}+${number2}=?`)
      var answer = number1 + number2
      console.log(answer)
      setTimeout(() => { 
        if(message.content.channel === answer){
          return message.reply("Correct!")}
        else{return message.reply(`sorry, either your answer was incorrect, or you ran out of time! the answer is ${answer}, please use __s!mathMinigame__ to try again!`)}}, 5000);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use a `MessageCollector`. Check out the docs for `channel.createMessageCollector()`: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector